# Add div classes based on for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function that add some classname to multiple divs based on a variable. Those classnames will be used for a star rating system.

I'm looking for an end result like this when `productScore` equals `3.5`:

```
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star semi"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star off"></span>
```

So basically there are 3 classnames to be added -> `on`, `off` and `semi`

So what I have is this:

```
function reviewStars(productScore, container){
  for (i=0; i < productScore; i++) {
    var starClass = productScore - i >= 1 ? 'on' : (productScore - i >= 0.5 ? 'semi' : 'off') 
    $(container).html('<span class="star fa fa-star' + starClass + '</span>')
  }
}
```

I want to use this function throughout my website. So it's reusable whereever I want. Like so:

```
 function initOfferList(){
      // ... code ... 
      $.each(data.products, function(i, product) {
       // ... more code ... 

        var productScore = (product.score * 5) // example 3.5
        var stars = reviewStars(productScore, '.item-rating')
        content += '<div class="item-rating">'+ stars +'</div>';

         // ... more code ....

      }
```

My code keeps returning `undefined`. I can't figure out why it is undefined.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: `reviewStars()` doesn't returns thus getting `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if function reviewStars return a string, your code will work.

```js
function reviewStars(productScore){
  var container='';
  for (i=0; i < productScore; i++) {
    var starClass = productScore - i >= 1 ? 'on' : (productScore - i >= 0.5 ? 'semi' : 'off') 
    container+='<span class="star fa fa-star' + starClass + '></span>'
  }
  return container;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to close the `span class` :) It should read -> `'<span class="star fa fa-star' + starClass + ' " ></span>'` So the double quote on the end

Comment: @Meules oh yes I forgot  :p

Answer (score 0):

What I see in your code maybe you don't need `container`

```js
function reviewStars(productScore){
  var result = '';
  
  for (i=0; i < productScore; i++) {
    var starClass = productScore - i >= 1 ? 'on' : (productScore - i >= 0.5 ? 'fa-star-half-alt semi' : 'off');
    result += '<span class="star fa fa-star ' + starClass + '"></span>';
  }
  
  return result;
}

// test
var cont = document.querySelector('.results');
var tests = [1,2,3,4,5,1.5,4.5,3.5];

for(var testScore of tests) {
  cont.innerHTML += '<li>'+reviewStars(testScore)+' | ' + testScore + '</li>';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="results">
</ul>
```